# Paypal customized user checkout

Tags: paypal, fuelphp

Is there any known way (an api or something of the sort) that I could use to create my own user checkout experience for Paypal?

So, for instance, the user clicks my donate button which takes them to my donate page. I collect the needed user information and pass it securely to paypal using some auth method without ever redirecting away form my site or using their "Customize your Payment Page" (which is entirely not customizable enough for me).

I've looked through their myriad of api's but haven't found anything useful yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [Direct Payment API](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside).  In order to use it, though, you need to have a Payment Pro account with PayPal.

If you plan to implement it with FuelPHP, then there is a feature rich, driver based, package [here](https://github.com/calvinfroedge/FuelPay).